# magento 2 how to show minicart in custom Popup?

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

magento 2 how to show minicart in custom Popup ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sample. You need to modify your way:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers"/>
    <update handle="checkout_cart_sidebar_item_price_renderers"/>
    <update handle="checkout_cart_sidebar_total_renderers"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block name="popup_minicart" as="popup_minicart" template="SR_MagentoCommunity::minicart.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart</item>
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/content</item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="subtotal.container" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">subtotalContainer</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/subtotal</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="extra_info" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">extraInfo</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="promotion" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">promotion</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/templates/minicart.phtml

```
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template */ ?>
<div style="display: none" id="popup-mpdal">
    <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    window.checkout = <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSerializedConfig() ?>;
</script>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-block='minicart']": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
        },
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif') ?>"
        }
    }
    </script>
<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                        $('#popup-mpdal').hide();
                    }
                }]
            };

            $('#popup-mpdal').show();
            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-mpdal'));
            $("#popup-mpdal").modal("openModal");
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: ok checking and let you know

Comment: Here may i customise also content.html ?

Comment: For customization change <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/content</item> this template inside your module

Comment: Thank you so much man accepted answer and upvote.

Comment: Hi it open popup with minicart data but if i try to change qty from popup nothing happen , it should show update button just like minicart

Answer (score 0):

avove minicart page working fine, i need spport any one, when clik add to cart button, show minicart page with detils

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.3.p2: i wanted to do some changes minicart page, when click add to cart button, minicart popup page open with cart items only